# navbar from left side to top using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been having a hard time getting the hamburger menu to work onnce the screen size decreases to anything below 1200px. How can I get my list items to show up below my top nav bar?

This is what I have so far:

```css
.mainBackground {
  background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/knaguibimages/image/upload/o_65/v1474765365/Background_p3qqpv.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .body-wrapper {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar {
    width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.navbar {
  z-index: 10000;
  background: rgba(30, 30, 31, 0.85);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 25px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }
}
ul li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.btn.responsive-menu {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .btn.responsive-menu {
    margin: 45px 50px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
}
.btn {
  color: #0067b5;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.current {
  color: white;
}
section {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 106px;
}
section .box {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: white;
}
#aboutMe-responsive {
  display: none;
}
#myPortfolio-responsive {
  display: none;
}
#contactMe-responsive {
  display: none;
}
#aboutMe {
  padding: 0 50px 20px 0;
}
#myPortfolio {
  padding: 0 50px 20px 0;
}
#contactMe {
  padding: 0 50px 20px 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #aboutMe {
    display: none;
  }
  #myPortfolio {
    display: none;
  }
  #contactMe {
    display: none;
  }
  #aboutMe-responsive {
    display: inline;
  }
  #myPortfolio-responsive {
    display: inline;
  }
  #contactMe-responsive {
    display: inline;
  }
}
.frame {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!--Navigation- Bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!--Navbar header-->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="navbar-brand text-center">
      <!-- <a href="#"> -->
      <i id="home" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
      <!-- </a> -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Hamburger menu-->
  <a class="btn responsive-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <i id="hamburger-menu" class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  </a>

  <!--Navbar Icon Section Navigation-->
  <!-- Add "in" when you want to collapse nav bar -->
  <div id="nav-section-selection" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!--About Me-->
      <li>
        <a href="#about">
          <i id="aboutMe" class="fa fa-user fa-2x current"></i>
          <span id="aboutMe-responsive">ABOUT ME</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!--Portfolio-->
      <li>
        <a href="#portfolio">
          <i id="myPortfolio" class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
          <span id="myPortfolio-responsive">MY WORK</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!--Contact-->
      <li>
        <a href="#contact">
          <i id="contactMe" class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span id="contactMe-responsive">CONTACT ME</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--Page Content Starts Here-->
<div id="pageContent">
  <!-- About Me Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="box">
      <h2 class="section-title">A Little About Myself</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-7">
          <figure class="frame">
            <img class="img-responsive about-me-img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/knaguibimages/image/upload/v1474765942/ProfilePic_bvn1gs.jpg" alt="Karim Naguib Profile Picture">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-5">
          <p>Hello! My name's Karim Naguib, and this page was developed to showcase my coding talent.</p>
          <p>I graduated from the <a href="https://uwaterloo.ca/"> University of Waterloo</a> in 2015, with a degree in Management Engineering.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Portfolio Section -->
  <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio-section">
    <div class="box">
      <h2 class="section-title">My Work</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="box">
      <h2 class="section-title">Get In Touch With Me</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this inside your navbar-header class:

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
```